# P2P app chat with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, peer

I followed the example on this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17321/A-simple-peer-to-peer-chat-application-using-WCF-n).

It worked pretty well - but it worked like a Chat Room.

I dont know how to just ***send and get message between just 2 clients***.

Can someone give me some advices to do that?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cant have only clients. You need to have both, a client and a server.

If you are trying to make a chat program with only 2 `users`, one of the users needs to act as a server and the other as the client. You only need to put a constraint on the server to allow only one client.